# Should I use the same training set from one epoch to another (convolutional neural network)

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

From what I know about convolutional neural networks, you must feed the **same training examples each epoch, but shuffled** (so the network won't remember some particular order while training).

However, in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6622.pdf) article, they're feeding the network 64000 **random samples** each epoch (so only some of the training examples were "seen" before):

> Each training instance was a uniformly sampled set of 3 images, 2 of
>   which are of the same class (x and x+), and the third (x−) of a
>   different class. Each training epoch consisted of 640000 such
>   instances **(randomly chosen each epoch)**, and a **fixed set of 64000
>   instances used for test**.

So, do I have to use the same training examples each epoch, and why?

*Experimental results are poor when I use random samples - the accuracy varies a lot. But I want to know why.*

Comment: That's probably not well understood! Most theoretical work is based on some strong assumptions (convexity, not the case here; the objective to optimize and co.). The original SGD proofs (of convergenc in the convex setting!) use the assumption of sampling with replacement, despite most people use sampling without replacement / aka cycling (motivated by [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)). Changes to the algorithm like that are also likely to induce the need for changes in parameters like learning-rate.

Comment: @sascha  the need for changes in parameters like learning-rate - by this you mean learning rate decay or some other sort of change? sorry if i sound dumb, but i'm new in machine learning

Comment: All might need to be changeg. In pure SGD, we are talking about initial learning-rate and decay, yes; sometimes even momentum. But all this stuff needs to be empirically analyzed, as theory does not help much

Comment: @sascha What about Adam? Or AdaGrad?

Comment: The same. These are not silver bullets. While often being more stable with less parameter-tuning, everything can happen. Non-convex (online-) optimization is a difficult thing.

Comment: @sascha It's weird, when I select the triplets **randomly** at each epoch, accuracy on test set varies around 50% (the first five epochs - 5 hours). When I cycle the training examples, accuracy goes to 70%. Is this normal? (The loss however decreases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time you might want to use as much data as you can. However, in the paper you cite they train a triplet loss, which uses triples of images, and there could be **billions** of such triples.

You might wonder, why introduce the idea of epoch in the first place if we're likely to obtain different training sets each time. The answer is technical: we'd like to evaluate the network on the validation data once in a while, also you might want to do learning rate decay based on the number of completed epochs.

Comment: It's weird, when I select the triplets **randomly** at each epoch, accuracy on test set varies around 50% (the first five epochs - 5 hours). When I cycle the training examples, accuracy goes to 70%. Is this normal? (The loss however decreases).